# Listeners disconnect from Icecast streams

Tags: sound, streaming, icecast

I'm doing a project on live audio streaming using Icecast and mixxx. I configured icecast server successfully. I'am able to listen the audio but sometimes **connection reset** occurs and the  connection can be again established by refreshing the page. This becomes a series issue when two or more listeners are present. how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Remedies depend on the root causing these disconnections. Likely we are faced with a bandwidth issue where listeners have a temporary drop, or the Icecast server is unable to provide streams at the rate demanded.

- In the likely case that we can not easily increase overall bandwidth we can try to priorize all streaming connections e.g. in the router.
- Alternatively we can try to gently increase the source timeout limits to disconnect clients in our `ìcecast.xml` configuration file in the section `<limits>`:

  ```
  <limits>
      ...
      <source-timeout>10<source-timeout>
      ...
  <limits>
  ```
- Another method to avoid disconnecting clients it to define a low bitrate fallback mount in the `<mount>` section.

Comment: Thank's for your kind attention. is this a bandwidth issue? we are trying to access the server with in the same router.